# Trying to run mariadb using homebrew and receiving the following error Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error

Tags: mariadb, homebrew

When I enter "brew services start mariadb" on the command line I receive the following error -

Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/jordanjohnston/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist` exited with 5.

I've seen folks having the same error and have tried entering -

"launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist"

followed by -

"launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist"

which does nothing for me, still receiving the same error. I have also entered "brew restart mariadb" which does not work either. I have also uninstalled and reinstalled mariadb which did not work. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: If you look at the contents of `homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist`, do all the file/paths exist? Is there a mariadb error log somewhere that has information related to the startup attempt?

Comment: How do I view the contents of homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist?

Comment: When I access the LaunchAgents folder there isn't any content.

Answer (score 0):

Also tried the same as you described with no luck. Finally ended up reinstalling Homebrew:

1. Make any pending updates for XCode. However, it might ask to also update the developer tools later on in step 4
2. Remove Homebrew. Make sure to have a backup of anything you want to save. For me, it was MariaDB and PostgreSQL databases. I also kept track of any important package I wanted to reinstall later:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

3. Remove any other pending directory as Homebrew suggests:

```
sudo rm -r /opt/homebrew
```

4. Reinstall Homebrew:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

5. Install MariaDB:

```
brew install mariadb
```

6. Start MariaDB:

```
brew services start mariadb
```

7. Check that is all good:

```
brew services list
```

You should see something like this:

[image: Services]